# Doing Inversion of Control (IoC) in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, design-patterns, inversion-of-control

Consider we have an interface called `MapService`, and two implementations: `GoogleMapsService` and `LeafletMapService`. I want a package (or Angular2?) to call the needed implementation rather than developers.

```
export interface MapService {
//define my API
}

@Injectable()
export class GoogleMapsService implements MapService {
//implement the API
}
```

That means, in the component I want the type of the service to be the interface (so not depending on the implementation):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MapService } from './map.service';
import { GoogleMapsService } from './google-maps.service'; 

@Component({
    template : `...`,
    providers: [GoogleMapsService]
})

export class MyComponent  {

  constructor(private googleMapsService : MapService) { //notice the type of the service here
  }
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Have you seen the official [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html)?

Comment: Isn't DI a form of IoC? What specifically do you want to do?

Comment: Use a token when you provide your service, and use `@Inject(theToken) private googleMapsService : MapService)`. But really, this is not needed 99% of the time, and mocking a concrete class is not a problem in JS/TS.

Comment: @JBNizet, thanks for your comment. Actually I want do that to make the use of the map service as abstract as possible.
That means if tomorrow, we change to a leaflet map, we'll only need to change the token and no more modifications would bee needed since both of service implement the same interface. Do you see what I mean? Maybe you have other suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So based on @jb-nizet's great comment; I've managed to do what I want using [InjectionToken](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/InjectionToken-class.html). Here is a code snippets:

```
import { Injectable, InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
export const GOOGLE_MAPS_IMPL = new InjectionToken<MapService>('googleMapImpl');

export interface MapService {
//define the API
}

@Injectable()
export class GoogleMapsService implements MapService {
//implement the API
}
```

And the component:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MapService } from './map.service';
import { GoogleMapsService, GOOGLE_MAPS_IMPL } from './google-maps.service'; 

@Component({
    template : `...`,
    providers: [{ provide: GOOGLE_MAPS_IMPL,  useClass:   GoogleMapsService }]
})

export class MyComponent  {
  constructor(@Inject(GOOGLE_MAPS_IMPL) private googleMapsService : MapService) { 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to use an abstract class instead of an interface.

```
  export abstract class MapService{
   // ...
  }
```

make your service implements this abstract class
and provide it

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MapService } from './map.service';
import { GoogleMapsService } from './google-maps.service'; 

@Component({
    template : `...`,
    providers: [
      { provide: MapService, useClass: GoogleMapsService }
    ]
})

export class MyComponent  {

  constructor(private googleMapsService : MapService) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following syntax in the providers array:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MapService } from './map.service';
import { GoogleMapsService } from './google-maps.service'; 

@Component({
    template : `...`,
    providers: [
      { provide: MapService, useClass: GoogleMapsService }
    ]
})

export class MyComponent  {

  constructor(private googleMapsService : MapService) {
  }
}
```

Note that you can do the same thing in the module scope.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work! 
It gives `TS2693: 'MapService' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

Comment: AFAIK we can't use interface as token